# Call GIMP via the command line to flatten and export a pdf image?

Tags: command-line, pdf, gimp, r

I've got a pdf figure with millions of semi-transparent points that I made in R. I want to flatten it to reduce filesize and then export it back out as a PDF (as a vector still, not a bitmap).

If there is a command line option, I can run it from within R using a `system()` call. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Radu Not a duplicate.  He wants to do this from within R.

Comment: @Seth I don't think there's as much focus on doing this *from* R as there is in whatever we suggest needing to be executable from the command line so that R could call it. The important bit that I missed before is that the they want the output to be a flattened vector.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at exporting from R in SVG (PDF will work, but SVG is easier to wrangle, being text based) and then run that through Inkscape.

Inkscape? A graphical application, Oli? Are you mad?

Actually [Inkscape can be run from the command line](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Can_Inkscape_be_used_from_the_command_line.3F) to do batch operations. I use it like that on a server (called from Python) to generate PDF certificates for a client of mine. Here's [its man page](http://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html).

It's most comfortable with SVG. If your input is an SVG you can vacuum-defs and export as PDF in one swift motion.